# Not able to enter the text on multiple lines of text column of the sharepoint list item in edit mode on IE 8 browser

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I am not able to enter the text in multiple lines of text column of the sharepoint list item on IE 8 browser.Please see the screenshot for clear understanding

[image: multiple lines of text column of the sharepoint list item in edit mode]

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are not using your browser in compatibility mode.
If you are using SP2010 you should ensure that the browser mode defined in the master page is IE 8.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

Comment: I am using the default master page of SP2010 and I have changed the master page settings as above tag but still its not working